# Sed replace string with special characters

Tags: regex, linux, string, bash, sed

I am trying to replace the below indicated string with special characters in a file, in linux. I tried using the backslash in front of every special char, but getting errors. Must be missing something. How do I achieve the below. Thanks in advance:

```
filter = [ "a/sda[0-9]*$/",  "r/sd.*/" ]   ---> Replace this line with below line

filter = [ "a/sda[0-9]*$/", "a/sdb[0-9]*$/", "r/sd.*/" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your example, this worked

```
sed 's@",@", "a/sdb[0-9]*$/",@'
```

output:

```
kent$  echo 'filter = [ "a/sda[0-9]*$/",  "r/sd.*/" ]'|sed 's@",@", "a/sdb[0-9]*$/",@'                                                         
filter = [ "a/sda[0-9]*$/", "a/sdb[0-9]*$/",  "r/sd.*/" ]
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. So, could  you help me understand this more. So we are initializing the current string as a variable and feeding it to sed, viz indicated by the @. That I get it. But, what about the below, what exactly is happening with the quotes?

sed 's@",@", "a/sdb[0-9]*$/",@'

Comment: In `sed`, any character after the `s` (substitute) command is taken as the delimiter.  So, `sed 's/a/b/'` is the same as `sed 's@a@b@'`.  Here, using `@` makes sure that you don't have to escape all the `/` etc. characters in your strings.

Comment: Ok, that's interesting. I was asking about this earlier:
",@",

Comment: Kent's solution is just like: `sed 's/",/", "a\/sdb[0-9]*$\/",/'`    
So, `",` is being replaced by `", "a/sdb[0-9]*$/",`

Answer (score 0):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) and columns strategy :

```
$ awk '{$3=$3 "a/sdb[0-9]*$/\042, "; print}' file.txt
filter = [a/sdb[0-9]*$/",  "a/sda[0-9]*$/", "r/sd.*/" ]
```